# Can't Install Django

Tags: python, django, pip

I can't install Django, I read that pip is included in python 3.4, but when I write following command:

> pip install django

this error appears:

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax.`

What I should do? Am I missing something? I'm using Python 3.4.2

Comment: Try reinstalling `pip`, maybe your version's broken

Comment: Are you typing the `>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` it looks like you're typing it in at the python interpreter (the `>>>`). `pip install django` needs to be run from a terminal.

pip is installed when you install python but it is a program in its own right not a python package/module. Docs are [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: well... It makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.4, pip installer is included by default with the Python binary installers.

```
~$ python -m pip install django
```

Read the docs:

- [pip included with Python](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html#pip-included-with-python)
- [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/#installing-python-modules)

or (on Debian/Ubuntu)

```
~$ apt-get install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using virtualenv for you django project, which includes pip. You can install virtualenv by:

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ [sudo] python setup.py install
```

Then cd to a folder you want to create a django project:

```
$ virtualenv ENV
```

then simply run

```
$ source bin/activate
```

You should be able to `pip install django` from there

Comment: You either need to `cd ENV` after creating the virtualenv or `source ENV/bin/activate`. virtualenv creates the environment in the path you give it.

Comment: It's also worth noting that if `python` defaults to python 2 on your system you might need to use `virtualenv -p python3 ENV` to make python 3 the default in the new environment.